# force jshint or syntastic to ignore html tags inside .js file

Tags: vim, jshint, syntastic

I use jshint + syntastic, and inside my js file

```
  class Channel extends React.Component{
      onClick() {
          console.log("I was clicked", this.props.name);
      }   
      render(){
          return (
            <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</li>
          )   
      }   
  }
```

line with `<li>` is an error "unclosed regular expression" how can i tell jshint or syntastic to ignore such errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jshint you can mark such code with `ignore:start` / `ignore:end` to disable the jshint:

```
  render(){
      // jshint ignore:start
      return (
        <li onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>{this.props.name}</li>
      )
      // jshint ignore:end
  }
```

Alternatively you can use [jsxhint](https://github.com/STRML/JSXHint) or [eslint](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html). Syntastic has checkers for both.

Update: eslint and jsxhint are not in the list of syntastic's default javascript checkers, so you will also need to add something like this into your .vimrc:

```
let g:syntastic_javascript_checkers = ['eslint']
```

Comment: Thanks, eslint is what i was looking for